# Eclipse/Tomcat Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, catalina, lifecycleexception

Everytime I want to run my Project on Tomcat(8) with maven in Eclipse I get following output:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/extJSWeb]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@703c75f2]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4969)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 10 moreCaused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@17318e84]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:703)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 13 moreCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
... 16 moreCaused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:137)
... 17 moreOkt 13, 2016 9:08:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor SCHWERWIEGEND: Error deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\ronal\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\conf\Catalina\localhost\extJSWeb.xml java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/extJSWeb]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Whats my problem?
jdk1.8.0_102
jre1.8.0_102

I reinstalled Tomcat many many times, other Projects working fine

Comment: Already seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487191/server-tomcat-v8-0-at-localhost-failed-to-start-failed-to-start-component-in-e/38593258

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check if there are redundant jar files included. Last time I met the similar issue, solved by removing some useless jar files.